# Problem with custom payment module magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

we are developing a payment gateway module for Magento 2.X but we have trouble figuring out why it is not working. We think maybe the /etc/di.xml file is not correct:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Girosolution\Girocheckout\Block\Form\Girocheckoutmethod\Default" type="Magento\Girocheckout\Block\Form" shared="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Girosolution_Girocheckout::form/paymentmethod/default.phtml</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="GirosolutionCommandPool" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="giropay_sale" xsi:type="string">Girosolution\Girocheckout\Gateway\Giropay\Command\SaleCommand</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="GirosolutionCommandManager" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManager">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commandPool" xsi:type="object">GirosolutionCommandPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandManagerPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="executors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="girosolution" xsi:type="string">GirosolutionCommandManager</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Then we have the file app\code\Girosolution\Girocheckout\Gateway\Giropay\Command\SaleCommand.php but the function execute() is never triggered when the customer try to pay with our payment method giropay. The code is:

```
namespace Girosolution\Girocheckout\Gateway\Giropay\Command;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\CommandInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\PaymentDataObjectInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Formatter;
use Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent;

 class SaleCommand implements CommandInterface
{
use Formatter;

/**
 * @var Transparent
 */
private $girocheckoutFacade;

/**
 * SaleCommand constructor.
 * @param Transparent $girocheckoutFacade
 */
public function __construct(
    Transparent $girocheckoutFacade
) {
    $this->girocheckoutFacade = $girocheckoutFacade;
}

/**
 * Executes command basing on business object
 *
 * @param array $commandSubject
 * @return null|ResultInterface
 */
public function execute(array $commandSubject)
{
    error_log("execute() in SaleCommand.php");
    /** @var double $amount */
    $amount = $commandSubject['amount'];
    /** @var PaymentDataObjectInterface $paymentDO */
    $paymentDO = $commandSubject['payment'];
    $payment = $paymentDO->getPayment();

    $storeId = $paymentDO->getOrder()->getStoreId();
    $this->girocheckoutFacade->setStore($storeId);

    /** @var \Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterface $token */
    $token = $payment->getExtensionAttributes()->getVaultPaymentToken();

    $request = $this->girocheckoutFacade->buildBasicRequest();
    $request->setAmt($this->formatPrice($amount));
    $request->setTrxtype(Transparent::TRXTYPE_SALE);
    $request->setOrigid($token->getGatewayToken());

    $this->girocheckoutFacade->addRequestOrderInfo($request, $payment->getOrder());

    $response = $this->girocheckoutFacade->postRequest($request, $this->girocheckoutFacade->getConfig());
    $this->girocheckoutFacade->processErrors($response);
    $this->girocheckoutFacade->setTransStatus($payment, $response);
}
}
```

We really need some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `giropay_sale` command will be never called because Magento Sales order management doesn't know anything about your custom commands.

You can look into [Magento payments dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html), where described the list of available payment operations.

About `sale` command, according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7449) Sales order management does not provide an ability to call `sale` operation, but you can write strategy, which allows processing sale and capture operations.
As the example, you can look into [Braintree payment method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/etc/di.xml#L128-L130) where this problem is solved by using strategy.

**UPD**: I've written a [post](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/The-Magento-Sale-Payment-Operation/ba-p/67251) about implementing the `sale` payment operation for a custom payment integration.